# What kind of IP address is this? (WIN-F9PTTKUMI2U:29901)

Tags: windows, networking, bittorrent, utorrent

While downloading a file with μTorrent, I noticed a strange peer with an address that was not an IPv4 or IPv6 address.

μTorrent showed it as `WIN-F9PTTKUMI2U:29901`.

What kind of address is this?

Answer (score 25):

### "What kind of IP address is this? (WIN-F9PTTKUMI2U:29901)"

`WIN-F9PTTKUMI2U:29901` is not an IP address.

It identifies a socket connection of a particular μTorrent peer and has the format hostname:port.

- `WIN-F9PTTKUMI2U` is the hostname.
- `29901` is the port number.

---

### Peers

> The Peers tab is where you'll find information about all the peers you
> are currently connected to on the selected torrent. The following is a
> description of each column:
>
> - IP displays the peer's IP address and the flag of the country they're from. **If Resolve IPs is enabled, the country flag and
>   hostname will be displayed instead**.

Source [Peers](http://www.bittorrent.com/help/manual/appendixa010503)

Comment: Indeed. It’s likely from the local network and a NetBIOS name.

Comment: It's not a particularly weird hostname either; recent Windows versions generate such names automatically, instead of asking during installation.

Comment: It's times like these where BitTorrent really needs built-in messaging capability so you can find the person on your same network with similar tastes in...  Linux distribution ISOs.

Comment: @Brad What version of FreeBSD do you run? Did you even get it to work yet?

Comment: To be more specific, it isn't simply an address, it is a socket. The first part is a host name or address specifying which allows routing to the specific device, the second part is the port number which allows routing to the specific listening application.

Comment: @MaQleod Goodpoint. I've made it clear in the answer.